# 2 picker not displaying values

Tags: objective-c, uipickerview

I currently have 2 pickers set to my viewController.h

```
@interface viewController : UIViewController <UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPickerView *lPicker;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPickerView *rPicker;

@end
```

My lPicker.tag = 0, and rPicker.tag = 1

In my implementation file for viewController.m

I define the following methods...

```
NSArray *data1 = {@"one", @"two", @"three" };
NSArray *data2 = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: [UIImage imageNamed:@"img1.png"],[UIImage imageNamed:@"img2.png"], nil];

-(NSInteger) numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView*)pickerView {
    return 1; //both contain only 1 column
}

-(NSInteger) pickerView:*UIPickerView *) pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    if(pickerView.tag == 0) return data1.count; if(pickerView.tag == 1) return data2.count;
}
```

Now i'm having trouble with the following, on the lPicker I want to display the values from data1, and on the right picker I want to display values of data2.

I've tried creating the method -(id)pickerView but that can't return NSString * and UIImageView at the same time.

Doesn't work if I implement something like...

```
-(id) pickerView:(UIPickerView *) pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *) view {
    if(component == 0) {
        UILabel *label = [UILabel alloc];
        label.text = [data objectAtIndex:row];
        [view addSubview:label];
        return view;
    }
    if(component == 1) {
        UIImageView *image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: [data2 objectAtIndex:row]]; 
        [view addSubview: image];
        return view;
    }
    return view;
}
```

Comment: How about using two different objects as the delegate / data source for these two picker views? Then you wouldn't be confusing yourself.

Comment: "but that can't return NSString * and UIImageView at the same time." No, but it can return _a label containing the string_ and an image view at the same time.

Comment: Is that a typo? The last method shouldn't be `numberOfRowsInComponent:`.

Comment: @rmaddy yes it was. I fixed it. I've tried implementing what Matt had suggested, by keeping one picker and creating 2 columns, one which displays UILabels and the other displaying UIImageView, but it still shows ? marks and not the real data.

Comment: That's still the wrong method.

Comment: @rmaddy I can't take the default method from -(void) or -(NSString*) and change it's type? If not, what should be the correct method?

Comment: The last method in your question is called when the user selects a row in the picker view.

Comment: You need the `pickerView:viewForRow:forComponent:reusingView:` method.

Comment: Your code makes no sense. `didSelectRow` doesn't return a value.

Comment: @rmaddy I tried what you suggested and updated my code. The goal would be to create a label if component = 0 or an image if component = 1. Since the method is returning a view, I'm adding the label/image to be a subview of view. However, this isn't working as it doesn't add anything and returns a blank picker.

Comment: @matt I was using the incorrect method, I'm trying to display the two arrays as two separate columns on my picker.

Comment: You are mistakenly assuming that `view` isn't `nil`.

Comment: Well that isn't the question you asked. You very specifically said there are two different pickers. And you're still saying it. Two pickers is not the same as one picker with two columns. - Unfortunately I only get one "unclear what you're asking" vote and I've already spent it.

Comment: @rmaddy if I check for the view being nil in that method, it crashes. Similarly, if I alloc the view in that method it crashes.

Comment: @matt I realize that there isn't a need for 2 pickers, if I'm able to display images in one column of a picker, and strings in another. Should I delete my question if it has changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As written at the moment, you are making bad assumptions about the reuse view. You also need to change how you determine which picker is being used. And fix the return value of the method.

Try this:

```
- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view {
    if (pickerView.tag == 0) {
        UILabel *label = (UILabel *)view;
        if (!label) {
            [[UILabel alloc] init];
        }
        label.text = data1[row];
        [label sizeToFit];

        return label;
    } else {
        UIImageView *image = (UIImageView *)view;
        if (!image) {
            image = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
        }
        image.image = data2[row];
        [image sizeToFit];

        return image;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, that clarified a lot. Sorry for my confusing question, I've only been coding with xcode for 2 days.